# Globally catching Exception

Tags: java, exception

I am working on a large scale application. I carefully try to handle all exceptions (and prevent them beforehand if possible). But as the application is large scale, sometimes some exceptions are thrown. When working in my development environment (i.e. starting the application from eclipse), I can see where the application occured, go there, and see what I can do about it. The problem is that - while developing - I have other people already "sort-of-test-working" with the application (inside the company). They give me a lot of feedback, which I like. Now if an exception is thrown in their application, there is no way for me to tell where this exception was created.

I have seen applications that show uncatched exceptions to the user over a dialog. While I surely don't want this to happen in the customer version, it might be of great help if I could do that in the debug version. Is this possible?

In short: **Is it possible to catch all thrown and uncatched exceptions of a multithreaded Java application?**

EDIT: I was asked, how the code is run. I create a runnable jar in eclipse containing all the libraries and class files. Then I pack this jar into an executable using [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). This executable is then used to run the application (it is packed into a setup.exe together with the ressource files using [Innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), but I guess this is not so important).

Codewise, I have a ThreadManager that starts all neccessary classes (including gui), but does not neccessarily keep a handle to all those classes.

Comment: "there is no way for me to tell where this exception was created" - do you not get a stack trace? If not, fix *that*...

Comment: @JonSkeet How do I "get" the stack trace? I can see it if my application is run in eclipse (as the stack trace is dumped into the console), but when someone else starts it, it is packed into a jar and not run from within eclipse.

Comment: Well we don't know a lot about how the code is being run or how you're finding out about the exceptions at all, which makes it very hard to answer...

Comment: @JonSkeet I added an edit. If you had some code in mind, I can add that as well. I don't find out about the exceptions (at least the ones that are not handled by me), that's my problem. If an exception is not caught, it will just crash my application, or make it unresponsive, or induce wrong behaviour, or have no effect on the application... I just want all those unhandled exception to be shown somewhere (dump into file, dialog with exception, or so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` to handle all uncaught `Exceptions`.

See [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_uncaught_handler.shtml)

Comment: That looks interesting. I will take a look at that.

Comment: This way you can get all `Exceptions` but your application still will crash. Use it only to find mistakes and then correct them

Comment: That's actually what I want. I don't want to globally catch Exceptions and handle them. That would be bad practice I think. What I want is to see where those Exceptions occur and then correct them in the code, so they don't appear anymore.

Comment: Ok, that's a good way. I used it to create my own Logger while writing on android, because there is no any another way for me to catch them in android

Answer (score 0):

You should have a log where all exceptions are written. Furthermore, if you are using log4j, you could use the org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender which will send you an email if an error was logged. This way you get an email every time an exception occurs in the application.

Answer (score 0):

So you need each thread to catch all Throwable's (not just Exceptions) before dying and to dump them in a log.

Catching can be done in 2 ways:

a) override run() with

```
try {
   super.run()
 } catch(Throwable ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace(logWriter);
 }
```

b) use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`

If you use ThreadManager, then create your own ThreadFactory which creates threads which log exceptions in one way or another.

Comment: Thanks, I like the seconds approach + the ThreadFactory suggestion.